# Did visual studio code implement find and replace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am reading https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics.

I see that there is mention of a find and replace coming soon.  I am wondering if this has been created? Or if anyone has figured out a workaround to doing a replacement.  I need to replace a certain property in my application 300 times and do not want to do this manually.

Comment: No, not yet. You can use any other editor for that (NotePad++, or similar)

Comment: Oh, I was thinking on "find and replace in files" taking the body of the question, not regular find/replace